# How to display events on a map?

Tags: civievent, wordpress

In the project I am working on a user can create an event with also a postal code information and address. I want to create a page where these events are all shown on a map, how can I do this with Civicrm or another wordpress plugin? The events are in Civicrm db.

Comment: Not posted as an answer, since you ask about WordPress, but in Drupal this is relatively easily handled with Views and a mapping plugin that can send coordinates to Gmap, OpenLayers, Leaflet, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's anything out of the box that does this. But if you're comfortable with PHP/JavaScript then it's not too tricky.

I'd create a WordPress template for that particular page, grab the event data using the API, and manually populate a google map. Untested code based on a similar thing we did recently:

```
<?php 

/*
Template Name: Your Template
*/

get_header(); 

?>

<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<!--needs loading before the footer-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<?php

//initialising CiviCRM Plugin
if (!civicrm_wp_initialize()) {
        return '';
    } 

require_once 'api/api.php';

//Grab data from API
$result = api call

//print json-encoded version
echo "var events = " . json_encode($result);

?>

<script type="text/javascript">

//set up the map
var map;

function initialize() {

    //map properties
  var mapProp = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.156594, -3.847324),
    zoom:6,
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  //set up map
  map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

  //loop through event data
  jQuery.each(events.values, function(key, data) {

  //get lat and long
  //this is made up - adapt for where the lat/lng actually are in the data
  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.geo_code_1, data.geo_code_2); 

 //create marker for each event
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            title: socName,
            map: map
        });         

    });

}

//initialize the map
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>

            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
            <div id="googleMap"></div>
            <?php the_content(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Regarding the API calls, it looks like you'd need a few:

This'll get you the event title and its 'location block id':

```
$resultEvent = civicrm_api3('Event', 'get', array(
  'sequential' => 1,
  'return' => "loc_block_id,title",
));
```

you'd then need to look up the location block id for each event:

```
$resultLocBlock = civicrm_api3('LocBlock', 'get', array(
  'sequential' => 1,
  'id' => id from first query,
));
```

this'll then return an address ID, which you can look up with:

```
$resultAddress = civicrm_api3('Address', 'get', array(
  'sequential' => 1,
  'id' => address id from second query,
));
```

and the resulting array will contain the latitude and longitude.

It *might* be possible to do all the above in one go using [chaining](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Chaining).

Comment: Be cautious about loading JS files directly into the template on WP; you could be loading duplicates. I recommend checking this out: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Comment: ah yes, I do remember this being a bit of a desperate move to get jQuery loading *somehow*. Should do it with the map code too. Thanks!

Comment: hi thanks @AndrewWest when you write:
//Grab data from API
$result = api call

Where can I find some sample API calls that will return a list of location  by evengs?

Comment: I've updated my answer with some API calls. Bit more fiddly than I expected.

Answer (score 0):

Create page in wordpress and include CiviCRM event using civiCRM Component in the page and also their are may wordpress plugins like (embed-google-map) 
you can use for map location